# chkdsk produces different errors every time after 40 tries

Tags: windows-7, chkdsk

I was getting a BSOD even when trying to boot into safe mode, so I booted from the Windows 7 install disk, pressed Shift+F10 to enter command prompt mode right away (because I have several operating systems on this system, the infinitely despicable so-called "Repair Mode" -- what a misnomer! -- takes about 40 minutes searching for operating systems to "repair").

Then I determine which drive letter is associated with the system disk in question, then enter CHKDSK  /F

It found errors the first couple of times and claimed to have repaired them, and eventually it reported that it had found no errors. But I've learned over the years that this can be a lie, so I've gotten in the habit of running the command again and again until it claims it found no errors twice in a row.

I've now run it about 40 times, and every single time now it reports errors, typically first the same one or two (corrupted attribute record x), then always one or more **different** error(s) every single time! Sometimes it reports that the volume is in use by a different process and asks if I want to dismount it first (to which I answer yes), but what other process could possibly have it attached at this point?  Perhaps the infinitely stupid "searching for operating system" process, that's still running after all this time?

Anyway, what the heck do I do now?

Comment: Is your RAM OK?

Comment: Have you checked the disk SMART status? https://www.howtogeek.com/134735/how-to-see-if-your-hard-drive-is-dying/

Comment: I'm running MemTest86+ right now. I'll report back after a good long run. As for the SMART status, that's trickier since the disk at issue is a two-SSD RAID 0 array, and you can't test SMART on a RAID array. But after the RAM testing is done, I can separate the two SSDs temporarily and then test the SMART status on both individually.

Comment: MemTest86+ reported 12 errors, but I only now learned that it can't save a report. So I just started over using PassMark's MemTest86 V8 Free, which does save a report to the USB boot drive. Since I previously had XMP1 mode enabled, I have disabled it for this tool. it is most likely that it will also find errors, but the doc points out that given my Intel CPU, it will be too difficult to determine the specific problem DIMM from the report. Thus, I'll have to run it with one DIMM at a time. Is this correct, folks?

Comment: PassMark's MemTest86 V8.1 Free found NO errors with XMP1 disabled. Now running again with that mode enabled...

Comment: With XMP1 enabled, it found a few RAM errors. But since no RAM errors were found with XMP1 disabled, I decided to go ahead and run CHKDSK that way once again. Since I then had six error-free runs in a row, my take-away is that I don't need to replace any RAM but I should never enable XMP again. Please comment if that's unwise. Otherwise, this can be closed.